# "Notice: Undefined index: #tag in Drupal\Core\Render\Element\HtmlTag::preRenderHtmlTag()"

Tags: 8

I keep getting the following error on a Drupal 8 site:

> Notice: Undefined index: #tag in Drupal\Core\Render\Element\HtmlTag::preRenderHtmlTag()

I have it from anonymous users, and I have it when I refresh admin/reports/dblog.

I usually get 4 messages in a minute.
That is followed from this message:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor->processHtmlHead()

What can be wrong on the site?

Drupal: 8.3.0

Theme: Mayo

Modules:

- Add To Head 8.x-1.x-dev
- Better Exposed Filters 8.x-3.0-alpha2
- Blazy 8.x-1.0-rc1
- Calendar 8.x-1.x-dev
- CAPTCHA 8.x-1.0-beta1
- Chaos tool suite (ctools) 8.x-3.0-beta1
- Colorbox 8.x-1.3
- Display Suite 8.x-2.6
- DraggableViews 8.x-1.0
- Easy Breadcrumb 8.x-1.6
- Entity Reference Revisions 8.x-1.2+2-dev
- Google AdSense integration 8.x-1.0-beta3
- Google Analytics 8.x-2.1
- Layout plugin 8.x-1.0-alpha23
- Metatag 8.x-1.0
- Page Manager 8.x-1.0-alpha24
- Paragraphs 8.x-1.1
- Pathauto 8.x-1.0-rc1
- Redirect 8.x-1.0-alpha4
- scroll to top 8.x-0.x-dev
- Search API 8.x-1.0-rc2
- Simple XML sitemap 8.x-2.9
  – Sitemap 8.x-1.3
- Slick Carousel 8.x-1.0-rc3
- Slick Views 8.x-1.0-rc2
- Tagadelic 8.x-3.0-alpha2
- Taxonomy menu 8.x-3.3
- Taxonomy Views Integrator 8.x-1.0-beta1
- Token 8.x-1.0-rc1
- Views Accordion 8.x-1.0-beta2
- Views Autocomplete Filters 8.x-1.1
- Views breadcrumb 8.x-1.0
- Views Slideshow 8.x-4.4
- Views Templates 8.x-1.0-alpha1

Comment: Unfortunately this is hard to deduce without more information. It is likely a contributed module. What is the callstack generating the first error?

Comment: I'm in the early learning Drupal, and I condescendingly refer to my knowledge in this area...

Comment: Please update the question with the 8.x version of Drupal and all contributed modules you are using and the theme.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answrs :) You'll need to do some debugging to get more information about the problem before posting here - it's impossible to diagnose an issue from those two notices alone

Comment: F.e. from anonymous http://www.raz-v-god.com/happybirtday/cards/multasnye-otkrytki-s-dnem-rozdenia-tri-baraska i have a message: http://www.raz-v-god.com/2017-04-13%20(1).png

Comment: To make clearer what @Clive said, our purpose is not guessing what could cause those errors and post what we are guessing hoping to exactly find what is the problem in your case. Our aim is answering objective questions with a definitive answer.

Comment: I`m so sorry, but i`m from Ukraine, and speak on english, little. In order to clearly form the question, I should have more knowledge of Drupal. Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: Drupal core 8.3.0   Theme Mayo 8.x-1.3

Comment: Add To Head 8.x-1.x-dev (2016-дек-30)
Better Exposed Filters 8.x-3.0-alpha2
Blazy 8.x-1.0-rc1
Calendar 8.x-1.x-dev (2017-янв-28)
CAPTCHA 8.x-1.0-beta1
Chaos tool suite (ctools) 8.x-3.0-beta1
Colorbox 8.x-1.3
Display Suite 8.x-2.6
DraggableViews 8.x-1.0
Easy Breadcrumb 8.x-1.6

Comment: Entity Reference Revisions 8.x-1.2+2-dev (2017-фев-09)
8.x-1.2 (2017-Jan-30)
Google AdSense integration 8.x-1.0-beta3
Google Analytics 8.x-2.1
Layout plugin 8.x-1.0-alpha23
Metatag 8.x-1.0
Page Manager 8.x-1.0-alpha24
Paragraphs 8.x-1.1
Pathauto 8.x-1.0-rc1
Redirect 8.x-1.0-alpha4

Comment: scroll to top 8.x-0.x-dev (2016-янв-10)
Search API 8.x-1.0-rc2
Simple XML sitemap 8.x-2.9
Sitemap 8.x-1.3
Slick Carousel 8.x-1.0-rc3
Slick Views 8.x-1.0-rc2
Tagadelic 8.x-3.0-alpha2
Taxonomy menu 8.x-3.3
Taxonomy Views Integrator 8.x-1.0-beta1
Token 8.x-1.0-rc1

Comment: Views Accordion 8.x-1.0-beta2
Views Autocomplete Filters 8.x-1.1
Views breadcrumb 8.x-1.0
Views Slideshow 8.x-4.4
Views Templates 8.x-1.0-alpha1
all

Comment: The best I can say is that I had a similar issue with Google Tag Manager - but you don't have it listed. You have an empty attachment in the html_head array which is causing this, best guess. The offending module should check for values before adding the attachment, which was the fix in Google Tag Managers case (dev).

Comment: Thanks for Your advice. I'll check the possible modules and reports the result.

Comment: Unfortunately providing a list of modules you have installed isn't a way to narrow down the problem. You need to _debug_ this yourself, work out which module is causing the problem, check the issue queue for known bugs, and only after that ask a very, very detailed question here containing the source exact source of the error, what you want to do to fix it, and where your current efforts to do so are going wrong. At the moment it feels more like you're looking for a support forum rather than Q+A, we can't support the sort of back-and-forth it would take to get the required information from you

Comment: Thanks again, Kevin, the error that arose from module "integration with Google AdSense 8.in x-1.0-beta3"

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2837481